# Why is the logo not showing on my site? GET /static/img/ATbrAaMRc.jpg HTTP/1.1" 404 1778 is the error i am getting

Tags: django, python-3.x

I am trying to add a logo to my site, but for some reason it just isn't showing up.I have configured my code to the best of my knowledge but here is my code.
First i made sure **django.contrib.staticfiles** is included in my **INSTALLED_APPS**.

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'blog',
]
```

i then ensured i defined **STATIC_URL** in my **settings.py**. *I am only using one STATIC*

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIR = [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')]
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles')
```

In my templates, i used the static template tag to build the URL for the relative path using the configured STATICFILES_STORAGE

```
{% load static %}
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8"> 
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">

    {% block title%}
    {% endblock title%}

    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark">

            <a class="navbar-brand" href="{%url 'index' %}">
                <img src="{% static 'img/ATbrAaMRc.jpg' %}" alt='Image'>
            </a>
```

[image: here is my project directory tree structure]

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: try removing STATIC_ROOT, I think it might cause some problems

Comment: What if you place {% load static %} tag inside the HTML itself? Not outside of it

Comment: @AdilShirinov about the STATIC_ROOT, its unlikely to be  the issue because STATIC_ROOT is the single root directory from where the Django application will serve the static files in production.
The command **python manage.py collectstatic** will automatically compile all the static files throughout the project and dump it into a single root directory, which is declared in STATIC_ROOT.

Comment: @AdilShirinov {% load static %} is well placed according to all the articles i have read about this subject. Below is a link to one.( https://djangocentral.com/static-assets-in-django/ )

Comment: Try deleting the STATIC_ROOT and STATICFILES_DIR variable declarations. As far as I can see, it should work

Comment: @TookieWookie nope. That's not it. I have tried it already and look above for why it should not be a problem. I replied to it above.

Comment: Wait, I'm looking at your directory structure, have your tried moving the static folder so that it is a sub-directory of blog i.e. blog/static/ ?

Comment: @TookieWookie That works! Thank You. Do you know why i had to move it there for it to work?

Comment: As per the conversation above the solution @TookieWookie gave worked but not like i wanted it to as my static folder was not for that specific app, but then he gave me another solution as shown below, and that worked like i expected it to. so Thank You

Answer (score 1, accepted):

moving the static folder to the blog app worked.

Answer (score 1):

There was a typo in the original post.

`STATICFILES_DIR` was used instead of `STATICFILES_DIRS` (**Note the "S" at the end**).

Fixing this allowed the "static" folder to be stored outside of the "blog" folder.

(Source: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/static-files/)

Comment: The first solution you gave me worked, but not like i wanted it to as it was not specific to the blog app, but fixing that typo and moving my **static folder** back works like a dream. Thank You